# How To Set Data Per Page Itextpdf Java

Tags: java, itext

I made an export pdf system using the java Itext pdf library, but there is a problem when I want to split the data of each page, I want to dynamically divide the data of each page using input, how to do it?like the code below, but the result is not as expected

```
//looping data row
        PdfPTable itemTable = new PdfPTable(headerColumns.length);
        itemTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
        for(int i = 0;i< data.size();i++){

            // header area
            PdfPCell area = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.get(i).get("area").toString()));
            area.setPaddingLeft(4);
            area.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            area.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            itemTable.addCell(area);

            // header new_sa
            PdfPCell newSa = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.get(i).get("new_sa").toString()));
            newSa.setPaddingLeft(4);
            newSa.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            newSa.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            itemTable.addCell(newSa);

            // header new_sa
            PdfPCell saMtd = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.get(i).get("sa_mtd").toString()));
            saMtd.setPaddingLeft(4);
            saMtd.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            saMtd.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            itemTable.addCell(saMtd);

            // header sa_last_month
            PdfPCell saLastMonth = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(data.get(i).get("sa_last_month").toString()));
            saLastMonth.setPaddingLeft(4);
            saLastMonth.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            saLastMonth.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            itemTable.addCell(saMtd);

            //set maxmimum data per page 2
            if(itemTable.getRows().size() == 2){
                document.newPage();
            }
            document.add(table);
            document.add(itemTable);
        }
        document.close();
```

pdf result of the code above
[picture page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2om2.png)
[picture page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v84dP.png)

Comment: You say the result is not as expected. But what *do you expect?*

Comment: the results that I expect, such as data per page for example 2 , in the results of the image I include it is like a bug where the data on the initial page is 1 but the data is repeated on the 2nd page

Comment: If you don't want the data to repeat, then you should not add the same `itemTable` object again and again but instead create a new one at the start of the loop. I.e. you should pull the two lines into the loop that currently are before the loop.

Comment: its brilliant!!,You have saved my life.

Comment: Good! I'll post that as an actual answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you clarified

> the results that I expect, such as data per page for example 2 , in the results of the image I include it is like a bug where the data on the initial page is 1 but the data is repeated on the 2nd page

If you don't want the data to repeat, then you should not add the same `itemTable` object again and again but instead create a new one at the start of the loop.

I.e. you should pull the two lines into the loop that currently are before the loop, instead of

```
PdfPTable itemTable = new PdfPTable(headerColumns.length);
itemTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
for(int i = 0;i< data.size();i++){
    ...
    document.add(itemTable);
}
```

use

```
for(int i = 0;i< data.size();i++){
    PdfPTable itemTable = new PdfPTable(headerColumns.length);
    itemTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    ...
    document.add(itemTable);
}
```